# Нужен аналог array.map для c#. Необходимо поменять 2 элемента массива местами

Tags: javascript, c#, массивы

> **Задача: В массиве из 20 целых положительных чисел найти наибольший элемент и поменять его местами с первым элементом.**

Вот пример кода на js

```js
f = [0, 1, 2, 23, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19];
f = f.map((val, i, arr) => i == 0 ? Math.max(...arr) : (i == arr.indexOf(Math.max(...arr)) ? arr[0] : val));
console.log(f);
```

Необходимо похожее решение, но на языке c#. Вот примеры нерабочего кода.

```
arr = arr.Select((val, i, arr) => i == 0? Math.Max(arr) : (i == Array.IndexOf(arr, Math.Max(arr)) ? arr[0] : val)).ToArray();
```

Ошибка: Аргументы типа для метода "Enumerable.Select<TSource, TResult>(IEnumerable<TSource, Func<TSource, TResult>)" не могут определяться по использованию. Попытайтесь явно определить аргумент типа.

```
arr = arr.Select((val, i) => i == 0 ? Math.Max(arr) : (i == Array.IndexOf(arr, Math.Max(arr)) ? arr[0] : val)).ToArray();
```

Ошибка: Ни одна из перегрузок метода "Max" не принимает 1 аргументов.

*Есть идеи аналога array.map, но для c#?*

Comment: В чём заключается нерабочесть? Так-то у Linq правильные методы подобраны

Comment: Уберите arr из аргументов лямбды

Comment: При попытке удалить arr из аргументов лямбды, появляется 2 ошибки: "Ни одна из "Max" не принимает 1 аргументов."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если прямо портировать ваше решение на LINQ, то получится следующее:

```
arr = arr.Select((val, i) =>
            i == 0 ? arr.Max() :
                     (i == Array.IndexOf(arr, arr.Max()) ? arr[0] : val))
         .ToArray();
```

Но этот код далёк от оптимальности, т. к. он так каждой итерации вычисляет `Max`, а затем `IndexOf`, то есть время пробега квадратично по размеру исходного массива.

---

Более производительное решение, линейное по размеру массива, состоит в предварительном нахождении максимума (и его индекса) за один проход. Это проще всего сделать так:

```
var (maxVal, maxIdx) = arr.Select((val, idx) => (val, idx)).Max();
if (maxIdx != 0)
    (arr[0], arr[maxIdx]) = (arr[maxIdx], arr[0]);
```

Малоизвестный факт: кортежи реализуют `IComparable<>`, сравниваясь друг с другом лексикографически. (Поэтому я обошёлся без `MaxBy`, недоступного в стандартной библиотеке.)

Comment: Спасибо. Проблема оптимизации в данном проекте не имеет значения. Ваше решение работает.

Comment: @ExonegeS: добавил более производительное решение